# Select maximum accounts in one month with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have date like:

```
date|account|location_code
```

What I want is to grab maximum location per day per account with a SQL statement.

```
11/11/2013|456456|91458
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just looking for a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT date, account, MAX(location_code) FROM table
GROUP BY date, account
```

This will return the maximum location_code for each account in each day.

Comment: But this will only return maximum based on the digit but what I need maximum location code used if I use that example it will return maximum based on digit i.e 5000, 5001 and eventhouhg the first location used 100 times the other used only 2 times will still return the 5001